# ¿Cómo mostrar solo los registros relacionados de una tabla en laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenos días/tardes/noches,
Estoy haciendo un aplicativo en laravel el cual sirve como administrador de una veterinaria.
El problema que presento es que en el momento de mostrar los registros de mascotas en el perfil de usuarios, me muestra todos los registros, pero necesito que me muestre solo las mascotas de la persona dueña de el perfil. Intenté usando los modelos o llamando las tablas directamente de la base de datos pero siempre conseguía un error nuevo.

¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo? anexo mi código:

Vista del perfil del usuario:

```
<form action="{{ url('/usuario/'.$usuario->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{method_field('PATCH')}}
    
    
    <section class="page-section portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4 order-lg-1">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="assets/img/portfolio/si.jpg" alt="">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p class="masthead-subheading font-weight-light mb-0 text-center lolxd">{{ $usuario->Nombre }}</p>
                    <img src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$usuario->Foto }}" width="300" alt="">
                </div>         
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 order-lg-2"> 
                <div class="p-5">
                    
                    <h3 class="display-5">Información personal</h3>
                    <br>
                    <p class="lolxd2"><strong>Nombre:</strong>{{ $usuario->Nombre }}</p>
                    <br>
                    <p class="lolxd2"><strong>Apellido:</strong> {{ $usuario->Apellido }}</p>
                    <br>
                    <p class="lolxd2"><strong>Direccion:</strong>{{ $usuario->Direccion }}</p>
                    <br>
                    <p class="lolxd2"><strong>Mascota(s):</strong></p>
                    <a href="{{ url('mascota/create') }}" class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"> Resgistrar mascota nueva.</a>
                    @foreach( $mascotas as $mascota )
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-4 order-lg-1">
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$mascota->Foto }}" width="100" alt="">   
                            <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">{{ $mascota->Nombre }}</div>
                        
                            <a href="{{url('/mascota/'.$mascota->id.'/edit')}}">
                            Editar
                            </a>
                            <form action="{{url('/mascota/'.$mascota->id)}}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿Realmente quiere borrar esta mascota?')"
                            value="Borrar">  
                            </form>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                   
                  
                </div>      
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      </form>
```

Controlador de la vista del perfil:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $usuario=Usuario::findOrFail($id);
    $records['mascotas'] = DB::table('usuarios')
         ->join('mascotas', 'mascotas.usuario_id', '=', 'usuarios.id')
         ->paginate(5);
    return view('usuario.show', compact('usuario'),$records);
}
```

Tablas migradas a la base de datos:

```
Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('Nombre');
        $table->string('Apellido');
        $table->integer('Telefono');
        $table->integer('Celular');
        $table->string('Direccion');
        $table->string('Correo');
        $table->string('Foto'); 
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    
    Schema::create('mascotas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('Nombre');
        $table->string('Animal');
        $table->string('Raza');
        $table->integer('Edad');
        $table->string('Foto');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('usuario_id');
        $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Los modelos actualmente están vacíos, ya que no funcionó el método que había encontrado. Pero había intentado:
Modelo mascota:

```
class Mascota extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['usuario_id'];   

public function usuarios(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Usuario::class);
}    
}
```

y tambien intenté en el modelo Usuario:

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
public function mascotas()
{
 return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Mascota', 'usuario_id');
}
```

Agradezco cualquier aporte o ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Muéstranos tus modelos y las consultas o consulta que hayas tratado por favor

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ya edite la publicación mostrando lo que intenté en los modelos, actualmente están vacíos porque sólo me causaban errores en los que me pedía que la salida fuera un array, o las variables de la vista estuviesen indefinidas.

Comment: Entonces el filtro es el ID del usuario que inicio sesión?

Comment: Es el usuario que fue creado con anterioridad, la aplicación permite crear usuarios que serian los "clientes" y luego se le pueden asignar mascotas creándolas, pero ahí el problema de que en el perfil del usuario creado me muestra todas las mascotas.

Comment: Gabriel muestranos esos errores tal cual aparecen

Comment: Los modelos estan relacionados correctamente, por ello se puede hacer solo `Usuario::find($id)->with('mascotas');`

Comment: O simplemente acceder a los datos de la relación con esta sintaxis: `Usuario::find(algo)->mascotas` @JuanRivera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente te diría que tu consulta se puede quedar de esta forma:

```
$usuario = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

$records['mascotas'] = DB::table('usuarios')
                         ->join('mascotas', 'mascotas.usuario_id', '=', 'usuarios.id')
                         ->where('usuarios.id', $usuario->id)
                         ->paginate(5);
```

De esta manera los registros que recuperes estarán limitados a los que tengan como llave foránea el id del usuario que recuperamos en `$usuario`.

Pues actualmente tu join carece de alguna instrucción que filtre y en cambio de hecho debería estar mostrando todos los usuarios y todas las mascotas que tiene asociadas.

Por otro lado si fuera a nivel de uso de las [relaciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) lo puedes manejar de este modo:

```
$propietarioDeMascotas = Usuario::findOrFail($id)->mascotas;
```

Filtramos la usuario por su id y posterior accedemos a la relación definida

Y así para paginar los resultados

```
$propietarioDeMascotas = Usuario::findOrFail($id)->mascotas()->paginate(5);
```